# Exact same formula producing two different results depending on cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, heatmap, countif

I'm making a calendar heat map of my org's sessions per day. There might be easier ways to do it, but I have one sheet for a calendar, another listing every single session by day, and the heat map sheet that looks at the equivalent calendar cell and counts how many sessions match that date. Conditional formatting changes the colour of the date cell depending on the number. [Screenshot of sheet setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXCt8.png).  (sorry, can't imbed images)

Each cell on my heat map matches a cell on the calendar sheet, so each heat map cell contains:

> =countif(Sessions!$A:$A,'Calendar 2021'!*B5*)

with the *cell address* changing for each date.

It all looked good until one date cell returned the wrong count for that date. When I checked the formula for that date, I found that it did return the right count - when I copied it to a different cell.

It's the exact same formula in each cell :

> =countif(Sessions!$A:$A,'Calendar 2021'!C23)

but in columns A-L, it returns '3', and after column M it returns '4' (the correct result).
[screenshot of different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtRx1.png)

Any idea what's causing that?

If it's useful to have a look yourself, here's a version with the same problem (stripped of all data but the dates): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16xP_a_KgeIoqomdsk3kMUDuV2GyIVMoNoOusvfWJdNU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You have different formatting applied to the various cells: none of which are correct for your use, by the way.

In the cells producing a result of `3`, you have formatting set to "d". This means you're requesting that the format show the day of the week instead of the underlying number (meaning that the only possible returns for this formatting are the numbers 1 - 7). Since your underlying correct number is `4`, the `d` formatting assumes that `4` is a raw date. The date-time origin in Sheets is December 30, 1899, which corresponds to the number 0. So `4` would translate to January 3, 1900. And the day of the week (`d`) of that date was a Tuesday, which in Sheets, is day 3 of the week counting from Sunday ... hence your *formatted return* of `3`.

In the cells returning `4`, it is only a happy accident that they are; because you've got the formatting for those set to return a date-time. As it so happens, the raw number `4` is the same as the 4th day from the origin date in Sheets; so you *happen to be* getting a formatted return of `4`.

You *should* be selecting the entire range A:R in your heat map sheet and setting the formatting to simply '0', which means "the original raw number." Setting the formatting this way will not affect text, only numbers.

I should note that your formatting and data types in your sample sheet are all over the place. Some of your numbers are generated by formula. Some are raw dates. So when you set the whole thing to formatting `0`, many of your cells are going to show numbers in the 40000 range, corresponding to the number of elapsed days for the underlying date as marked from December 30, 1899. You'll need to be sure that every applicable cell in your heat map sheet contains a formula that returns the `COUNTIF`, *not* dates.